# Css specificity -- issues with link style in stylesheet

Tags: css, css-specificity

I'm getting really confused here with my stylesheet. I have a lot of specific link styles in my sheet, and for some reason randomly one of them will get overridden by something else when I check the page with Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug. After fiddling around with !important cases and realizing that they are slowly making my code absolutely terrible, I've removed them all and am trying to figure out how to organize my link style to get all the right styles in the right places without them being overridden.

Basically I have like so:

```
.newlinks a {
some styling}

.dl a {
some styling}

.abclink a {
some styling}
```

And .newlinks is getting the "some styling" from ".abclink a". I'm really confused why this is happening if the class has a specific name and not just like "p" or something. Any explanation would be helpful! Thank you!

edit: here is the order of the html

```
<div class="newlinks"><a href="#"></a></div>
more of the page..
<div class="abclink"><a href="#"></a></div>
<div class="dl"><a href="#"></a></div>
```

I could post the longer code if necessary, I just thought it might be a general issue with my ordering or wording or something.

editedit: here it the relevant css/html in a jfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Ub6er/

as you can see in the jsfiddle, the link in "underrighttext" is getting the style from .dl :(

Comment: How does your concerned HTML look like can you post that too...

Comment: i updated the original post, thank you for your help! I can upload a jsfiddle of the entire code if it's not just a general syntax issue

Comment: this would really not override but probably you may have done something wrong. please show a fiddle one.

Comment: alright one sec, I will try to get only the relevant parts, my css is over 3000 lines long

Comment: Yeah you may find the issue when making the JSFiddle, it sounds like overlapping class names or something. If you can get a working copy you'll probably get much quicker help in the future.

Comment: the jsfiddle has been added! the issue is still there :(

Comment: The jsfiddle does not match the description; there is no class `newlinks` to begin with. You should specify concrete which elements appear incorrectly in which way, so that people can immediately see what you regard as the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `underrighttext` is being styled like `dl` is because of how you've declared your CSS for `dl`:

```
.dl a, a:active, a:visited {
    ...
}
```

This selector, which I copy-pasted from your JSFiddle, will apply to all `a` in `dl`, but also to **all** `a:active` and `a:visited`. Not just the `a:active` inside of `dl`!

You need to fix your selectors for the active and visited state to be like this:

```
.dl a, .dl a:active, .dl a:visited { ... }
```

Right now, your active and visited links are just being styled with whatever was the last style parsed by the browser.

I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HzG8t/1/) with the correct CSS selectors. It should work now as you expect it.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much! I never knew this about my code.